# Notification body doesn't appear in release

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, alarmmanager

I'm using `AlarmManager.setExact` to schedule alarms in order to send local notifications to the user, I'm also sending the title and body of the notification inside the `Intent` of the alarm. Like this:

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(context, NotificationReceiver::class.java)
intent.putExtra("__title", title)
intent.putExtra("__body", body)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)

val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
```

And in my `BroadcastReceiver` I'm pulling the title and body from the intent and sending a local notification using `NotificationCompat`. Like this:

```kotlin
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    val title = intent.getStringExtra("__title")
    val body = intent.getStringExtra("__body")

    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "__main_channel")
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(body)
        .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(body))

        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)

        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_REMINDER)
        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)

        .setShowWhen(true)
        .build()

    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(0, notification)
}
```

Now the crazy thing is that this code is working just fine when I'm debugging, the notification (with its title and body) appears just fine:

[image: Notification working correctly]

But when I release the project to Google Play the notifications show without the body:

[image: Notification showing but without a body]

I spent days hunting this issue but I couldn't pinpoint how the body is getting lost.

I know this issue is too vague to be asked here, but at this point I'm very desperate and would appreciate any hints.

Comment: Have tried using another phones?

Comment: I have only one phone for testing, but I tried 3 different emulators (API 28, 29 and 30) and I'm having the same issue on all three of them.

Comment: Did you set also notificationChannel?

Comment: Yes, I create a notification channel as soon as the app starts then I push all my notifications to the same channel.

Comment: @HeysemKatibi Did you try hard code `title` and `body` values to make sure it always presents then build your app on release mode? Missing `body` field is also a possibility

Comment: @hientp No, The problem is this issue only surfaces on release versions, so it's very hard to debug it. and I don't feel comfortable releasing a version with hard coded notifications to all users.